# HighCharts: Enable/Disable tootip based on mouse click event

Tags: highcharts

I need to enable/disable tooltip based on mouse click event. I surfed the net but somehow the suggestions are not working.

Inside the `click` event I tried `chart.tooltip.hide();` but it didnt work. Even if it were to work I need to find the opposite of this function. `chart.tooltip.unhide();` and `chart.tooltip.show();` are not recognized.

I had read somewhere that  `chart.container.tooltip.enabled = true;` should work, but even this is not a working solution.

Will appreciate if anyone can help me dynamically hide/unhide the tooltip.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `chart.tooltip.refresh(point)`, for example `chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[2]);`